# How do I get ta.crossunder to calculate correctly?

Tags: pine-script

I am using ta.crossunder to Close a position in my strategy. It seems to signal a cross of two moving averages when there isn’t one. What am I doing wrong here?

And here is the code.

```
//MA User Input
ShortMALength = input.int(100, "Short MA Length", minval=1, maxval=300)
MediumMALength = input.int(30, "Medium MA Length", minval=1, maxval=300)
LongMALength = input.int(200, "Long MA Length", minval=1, maxval=300)

shortMALong=ta.hma(close,ShortMALength)
mediumMA=ta.hma(close,MediumMALength)
longMA=ta.hma(close,LongMALength)

//MA cross sell signal
LongCrossBuy = ta.crossover(shortMALong,longMA)
LongCrossSell = ta.crossunder(shortMAShort,longMA)

plotshape(LongCrossBuy, style=shape.triangleup, title="LongBuySignal", location=location.top, color=color.new(color.green,50),size=size.tiny)
plotshape(LongCrossSell, style=shape.triangledown, title="LongSellSignal", location=location.bottom, color=color.new(color.red,50),size=size.tiny)

strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, when = LongCrossBuy)
strategy.close("long", when = LongCrossSell)
```

[image: example chart]

Comment: Please don't post your code as a screenshot, but rather edit your question and add the code in plain text, formatted as code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I have updated the code as text instead of an image.

Answer (score 0):

I think you made a typo, and meant to write `shortMALong`

```
LongCrossSell = ta.crossunder(shortMALong,longMA)
```

Instead of `shortMAShort`

```
LongCrossSell = ta.crossunder(shortMAShort,longMA)
```